# Unable to rename Dataframe's column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When showing partitions of a table, using Spark 1.6.3, I am unable to rename the Dataframe's column.
In order to reproduce the problem, I build the following partitioned table

```
sqlContext.sql("create table test (foo string) partitioned by (dt string)")

val df = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("foo", 1), ("bar", 2)))
  .toDF("column", "dt")

df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("dt").insertInto("test")
```

I can retrieve the list of available partitions in the table

```
scala> sqlContext.sql(s"show partitions test").show

+------+
|result|
+------+
|  dt=1|
|  dt=2|
+------+
```

Now, I would like to rename the column using `withColumnRenamed` like this

```
sqlContext.sql(s"show partitions test").withColumnRenamed("result", "partition").show
```

Which fails with the following error message

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) result#835 missing from result#826 in operator !Project [result#835 AS partition#836];

I can get around this problem using a simple alias

```
> sqlContext.sql(s"show partitions test").select($"result".as("partition")).show

+---------+
|partition|
+---------+
|     dt=1|
|     dt=2|
+---------+
```

But why does it fail in the first place ?

Comment: `!Project [result#465 AS dt#466]` seems to be a hint. In particular `sqlContext.sql(s"show partitions test").withColumnRenamed("dt", "partition")` will work. This could be a bug in handling native Hive commands. After all there is no true execution plan there.

Comment: I'm sorry, the error message was from a previous attempt, I've edited my question with the updated error message. Sorry for the confusion. What could be a hint, is that it shows two different columns `result#835` and `result#826`.

Comment: Please update your questions tag for `Hive sql` as well